# how do you make text in html smaller every time it doesn't fit in the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a [simple html and css setup](https://codepen.io/happyprogrammer-code/pen/YzQVQoR) that looks like this

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ab! Non esse natus aliquid id est placeat dolorem velit explicabo.</p>
  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

and it looked like this

[image]

but then if I add more characters to it, it will spread outside of the containers which is expected

[image]

but how do you make it so that if the text were to spread out it will shrink instead to keep it inside of the container?

Comment: By "shrink"what do you mean? reduce in size to smaller font, cut some off - presumably the end; or just not show the text that is outside of the block like your last image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove height attribute...

```css
 .box{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="box">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ab! Non esse natus aliquorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ab! Non esse natus aliquorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ab! Non esse natus aliquorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ab! Non esse natus aliquid id est placeat dolorem velit explicabo.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add overflow to css.

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).